# O que representa o código f = Fernet(key) ao utilizar a biblioteca 'cryptography.fernet'?

Tags: python, criptografia

O programa consiste em encriptar uma mensagem com uma chave e depois desencriptar.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)
token = f.encrypt(b"my deep dark secret")
f.decrypt(token)
```

Alguém me consegue explicar o que a linha `f = Fernet(key)` faz ?

Answer (score 5):

Sem olhar a documentação da biblioteca já dá para dizer que o que ela faz é instanciar um objeto - em Python, via de regra, nomes em CamelCase são nomes de classes - se você "chama" uma classe, cria uma instância dela - e nesse caso, com a chave passada.

Esse objeto criado tem os métodos `encrypt` e  `decrypt` que usam a chave usada na criação do objeto para traduzir bytes entre criptografados e descriptografados.

O interessante de projetos em Python é que é fácil olhar seu código fonte - ou na pasta `site-packages`, onde ele é instalado em seu próprio computador, ou direto no repositório onde está o código fonte. Nesse caso, coloquei "pythn fernet github" no google, e o primeiro link foi direto para o arquivo que contém a classe, dentro do projeto "cryptography" de Python: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/src/cryptography/fernet.py

Dentro do arquivo temos a declaração da classe - o método `__init__` é bem didático:

```
class Fernet(object):
    def __init__(self, key, backend=None):
        if backend is None:
            backend = default_backend()

        key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(key)
        if len(key) != 32:
            raise ValueError(
                "Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes."
            )

        self._signing_key = key[:16]
        self._encryption_key = key[16:]
        self._backend = backend

    ...
```

Ou seja - ele prepara a chave para uso, traduzindo-a de uma representação em forma usável em URLs para uma sequência de 32 bytes, e separa os primeiros 16 como chave de assinatura, e os últimos 16 como chave de croptografia - além de selecionar um backend - O restante da classe é código para "pilotar"  os algoritmos em mais baixo nível, passando para os mesmos as chaves, trechos a criptografar com tamanho padronizado, dados extras de aleatoriedade como horário e um `salt` - de forma que o usuário final só precise de preocupar em chamar os métodos `encrypt` e  `decrypt`.